# Django test with allauth

Tags: django, django-allauth, django-testing

I want to test a `django` app with `allauth` with the scenario "that for unauthenticated users, they are **redirected** to the login page, which lists several **social network** options".

Therefore, the environment requires some social-app to be set up. So I did:

```
def set_up_allauth():
    site = Site.objects.create(name="localhost", domain="localhost")
    fb = SocialApp.objects.create(
        provider="facebook",
        name="Facebook",
        client_id="<id>",
        secret="<secret>",
    )
    fb.sites.add(site)
    fb.save()

class CollectionPageTest(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        set_up_allauth()

    def test_collection_visitor(self):
        # import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
        response = self.client.get(reverse("collection"))
        self.assertRedirects(
            response, reverse("account_login"), status_code=302
        )
```

If I put a `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` at the above indicated position, I can see that `SocialApp.objects.all()` contains the created `Facebook` app, but in the end of the test, I always get failure:

> ImproperlyConfigured: No Facebook app configured: please add a SocialApp using the Django admin

I wonder what is happening here and how to solve it? (I am guessing this is because the `.sites` is not hooked up to the current testing environment?)

---

The part of `settings.py` that concerns `allauth`

```
# ==============
# Django-allauth
# ==============
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    # Needed to login by username in Django admin, regardless of `allauth`
    "django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend",
    # `allauth` specific authentication methods, such as login by e-mail
    "allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend",
)

ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
# ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = "mandatory"
# ACCOUNT_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_AUTHENTICATED_REDIRECT_URL = "/app/"
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_AUTHENTICATED_REDIRECT_URL = ""

# The id of the working URL in the Sites table
# Currently the URL is http://localhost:8000/
SITE_ID = 1

SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    'facebook': {
        'SCOPE': ['email', 'user_photos', "publish_actions"],
        'AUTH_PARAMS': {'auth_type': 'reauthenticate'},
        'METHOD': 'oauth2',
        'LOCALE_FUNC': lambda request: 'en_US',
        'VERIFIED_EMAIL': False,
        'VERSION': 'v2.2'
    },
    'instagram': {
        'AUTH_PARAMS': {'auth_type': 'reauthenticate'},
        'METHOD': 'oauth2',
        'LOCALE_FUNC': lambda request: 'en_US',
        'VERIFIED_EMAIL': False,
    }
}

# The email backend for allauth
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    # Required by allauth template tags
    "django.core.context_processors.request",
    # allauth specific context processors
    "allauth.account.context_processors.account",
    "allauth.socialaccount.context_processors.socialaccount",
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
    'postman.context_processors.inbox',     # Django-postman
)

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "/user/dashboard/"
ROOT_URL = ''
```

Comment: please provide your settings.py

Comment: @Mikeec3: Hi, I attached the `settings.py`

Comment: now before you go on taking over the world, I'll try to recreate the problem.

Answer (score 3):

So the fixtures weren't working for me. I don't like fixtures anyway, so I came up with an alternate solution:

**SetupTestData.py**

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site

class TestData(TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):

        cls.current_site = Site.objects.get_current()

        cls.SocialApp1 = cls.current_site.socialapp_set.create(
            provider="facebook",
            name="facebook",
            client_id="1234567890",
            secret="0987654321",
        )

        cls.SocialApp2 = cls.current_site.socialapp_set.create(
            provider="instagram",
            name="instagram",
            client_id="1234567890",
            secret="0987654321",
        )
```

**test_collection_page.py**

```
from TestPath.tests.SetupTestData import TestData

class CollectionPageTest(TestData):
    def test_collection_visitor(self):
        # import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
        response = self.client.get(reverse("collection"))
        self.assertRedirects(
            response, reverse("account_login"), status_code=302
        )
```

Simply subclass the same TestData whenever you need these to be active.

Answer (score 1):

Use following fixture (put it in file social_apps.json, in fixtures folder of your app) to setup allauth and sites:

```
[
  {
    "model": "sites.site", 
    "pk": 1, 
    "fields": {
      "domain": "localhost", 
      "name": "localhost"
    }
  },
  {
        "model":"socialaccount.socialapp",
        "pk":1,
        "fields":{
            "id":"1",
            "provider":"facebook",
            "name":"facebook",
            "client_id":"0011223344556677",
            "secret":"012345678901234567890123456",
            "key":""
        }
  },
  {
        "model":"socialaccount.socialapp_sites",
        "pk":1,
        "fields":{
            "id":1,
            "socialapp_id":1,
            "site_id":1
        }
  }
]
```

Then, update your CollectionPageTest to include fixtures declaration:

```
class CollectionPageTest(TestCase):
    fixtures = ['social_apps']

    def test_collection_visitor(self):
        # import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
        response = self.client.get(reverse("collection"))
        self.assertRedirects(
            response, reverse("account_login"), status_code=302
        )
```